# Is there any custom PHP library or web-service that gives me list of all HTML and HTML5 tags?

Tags: php, web-services

Is there any custom php library or web service that gives me the list of all standard HTML/HTML5 tags ?

I am writing a custom PHP strip_tags for some requirements and instead of storing every HTML/HTML5 tags in a class private property (like an array), I was wondering if some service does exist that provides this functionality?

Comment: You mean an `array` with all the `html` tags, or a function that stores all the tags within a class private property?

Comment: I think Rafal approach is the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list isnt't that long. Create own:)
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/